# What directive will I use to initialize a control on page load?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I faced this question in interview, I was not able to answer it.

Comment: I'm thinking "ng-init" as initialize is the keyword in that sentence.

Comment: The real question is what is the "control"? This would determine your options for initialization. ng-init just runs some code soon as the page loads.

Comment: Yes the question was directive to initialize control on page load.

Comment: I saw the question, but I believe the point in an interview would be to ask some clarifying questions like "describe the control," "what do you mean by control," and "why on page load specifically?" Else the most generic answer you can give to this generic question would be to do ng-init and you can go into some details about ng-init if you know it, like at what priority it is run and why it's a good candidate over something else.

Comment: You are correct, it was kind of pre screening they just wanted wether I am acquainted to these directives,thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: If the interviewer was expecting ng-init as a correct answer, I wouldn't want to work for them anyway.  ng-init **is not** a page initialization directive, despite it's name.  It is *only* useful for specific props of ng-repeat.  Page initialization should *always* be done in a controller function.